# Some bug in Mac OS Safari with css "top" and jquery .onscroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, css-position, scrolltop

For reason I can't use `position: fixed;` (because it have some math around position), so I make simple example with `position:absolute` and change it's `top` with `scrollTop` of window.

http://jsfiddle.net/6yrhod1c/1/

You can try it in any browser (Chrome, FF, Opera, even Safari for Window) but in Safari on Mac it will have some lags and jumps.

Any ideas? May be add some attribute to `body` for more smooth animation?